Entry and Exit on same bar. Stoploss immediately executes on Entry
I am really struggling with trying to get my stoploss at the right position. What i am simply trying to do is to get a fixed stoploss with certain amount of ticks below my entry but no matter how i format the code the positions either disappear completely or it enters and closes immediately on the same bar/candle. the condition 100% works fine i already checked that.
Please someone help me its driving me insane. i tried chatGPT and different forums but can't find anything
this is the code format
//@version=6
strategy("My strategy")


// placing orders

stoplossTicks = 50000 * syminfo.mintick

if (condition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Long", loss = stoplossTicks)

I want fixed stoploss based on certain amount of ticks below my entry.

the logic is correct, but 50000 ticks is too much, that's why you are not getting exits
